# Add Class to Param tag - JavaApplet

Tags: java, applet

I have an applet code like this:

```
<applet type="applet" codebase="." code="ViewerApplet.class" align="center" width="100%" height="600" archive="icepdf-core.jar, icepdf-viewer.jar, icepdf-applet.jar">
<param name="image" value="my_logo.gif" type="image/gif">
<param  name="java_arguments" value="-Xmx128m" />
<param name="classloader_cache" value="true" />
<param name="url" value="<%=test%>" />
</applet>
```

I want to add style to this line. `<param name="image" value="my_logo.gif" type="image/gif">`

It means, before loading the pdf i have replaced the java logo with my logo.
The logo should be aligned at center with some style. Is it possible to add style to the 
above `param` tag.

Thanks -
Haan

Answer (score 1):

No, the param tags are only for sending parameters to the applet.  Definition on w3c:

The 'param' tag is used to define parameters or variables for an object or applet element.

Imagine that the param tag is the same as sending a string to a function, you can't format the string by sending it in a different way.